# JavaScript promises how to hide some details?

Tags: javascript

I want to send some secret informations (like password) to API. Is it possible to hide this informations in sources?

Comment: *Is it possible to hide this informations in sources?* I didn't understand!

Comment: JavaScript running where, with code loaded from where, should send whose passwords to which API and hide this from whom?

Comment: What are your purposes for this? It seems like you might be having the wrong approach. Javascript is generally never safe when you want to hide information from the client, as all javascript is run client side. If you want to make it "secure" in Javascript terms, your best bet is to encrypt your data.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not.

The best you can do is obfuscate the authentication details, but even then all it takes is someone using their browser's developer tools to snoop on the network traffic to find out the password.

You'll have to proxy requests like that through your server (that knows the credentials) to keep them hidden from clients.